# BetterPlayer throws an error when going fullscreen when using with miniplayer in Flutter

Tags: flutter, fullscreen, flutter-video-player

In my flutter app I have a [miniplayer](https://pub.dev/packages/miniplayer) with a [better_player](https://pub.dev/packages/better_player) (a plugin for playing videos based on [chewie](https://pub.dev/packages/chewie)) in it. When I want to go fullscreen in my better_player video, it shakes a few times and then throws an error:

[image]

**Here are the logs:**

```
    V/AudioManager( 4491): playSoundEffect   effectType: 0
V/AudioManager( 4491): querySoundEffectsEnabled...
D/HwAppInnerBoostImpl( 4491): asyncReportData com.example.cook_it,1,1,1,0 interval=2270
D/HiTouch_PressGestureDetector( 4491): HiTouch on notch display, width corret:81
I/HiTouch_HiTouchSensor( 4491): ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
W/libEGL  ( 4491): EGLNativeWindowType 0x72af668010 disconnect failed
D/mali_winsys( 4491): EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
W/libEGL  ( 4491): EGLNativeWindowType 0x72c1a8b010 disconnect failed
D/mali_winsys( 4491): EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
D/HwAppInnerBoostImpl( 4491): asyncReportData com.example.cook_it,1,2,1,11 interval=2474
I/ViewRootImpl( 4491): jank_removeInvalidNode all the node in jank list is out of time
W/libEGL  ( 4491): EGLNativeWindowType 0x72af668010 disconnect failed
D/mali_winsys( 4491): EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown building ValueListenableBuilder<double>(dirty, dependencies: [_LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#b0f8f], _InheritedTheme], state: _ValueListenableBuilderState<double>#b21c7):
type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'double'

The relevant error-causing widget was
ValueListenableBuilder<double>
package:miniplayer/miniplayer.dart:157
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      borderDouble
package:miniplayer/src/utils.dart:24
#1      _MiniplayerState.build.<anonymous closure>
package:miniplayer/miniplayer.dart:170
#2      _ValueListenableBuilderState.build
package:flutter/…/widgets/value_listenable_builder.dart:187
#3      StatefulElement.build
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4691
#4      ComponentElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4574
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
D/HwAppInnerBoostImpl( 4491): asyncReportData com.example.cook_it,1,1,2,0 interval=3360

════════ Exception caught by foundation library ════════════════════════════════
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called when widget tree was locked.
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by foundation library ════════════════════════════════
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called when widget tree was locked.
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
D/HiTouch_PressGestureDetector( 4491): HiTouch on notch display, height corret:81
W/libEGL  ( 4491): EGLNativeWindowType 0x72af668010 disconnect failed
D/mali_winsys( 4491): EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
W/libEGL  ( 4491): EGLNativeWindowType 0x72c1a8b010 disconnect failed
D/mali_winsys( 4491): EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
D/HwAppInnerBoostImpl( 4491): asyncReportData com.example.cook_it,1,2,2,9 interval=3525
W/ACodec  ( 4491): forcing OMX state to Idle when received shutdown in ExecutingState
I/ExoPlayerImpl( 4491): Release e8aaab7 [ExoPlayerLib/2.14.2] [HWCLT, CLT-L29, HUAWEI, 28] [goog.exo.core]
E/BufferQueueProducer( 4491): [SurfaceTexture-0-4491-9] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
I/chatty  ( 4491): uid=10264(com.example.cook_it) JNISurfaceTextu identical 3 lines
3
E/BufferQueueProducer( 4491): [SurfaceTexture-0-4491-9] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
I/chatty  ( 4491): uid=10264(com.example.cook_it) JNISurfaceTextu identical 1 line
```

Can someone help me with solving this issue?

PS. I tried using chewie instead of a better_player but the result was almost the same.

Answer (score -1):

I found the issue, it was in my own code and it wasn't related to packages.

Comment: Explain how did you solve the problem!